# Jwplayer().seek is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using jwplayer().seek() in two places. One for avoiding fast forward and another , when the page returns after refresh ( seeks to the position from where the page was refreshed.)

The second case is working properly, but in the first case the jwplayer().seek() doesn't seek to specified position.

My code:

```
 var seeking = false;
var currentPosition = 0;
jwplayer().onTime(function (callback) {
currentPosition = callback.position;
});
jwplayer().onSeek(function (position, offset) {
var localPosition = currentPosition;
if (!seeking) {
seeking = true;
jwplayer().seek(localPosition);
} else {
seeking = false;
}

});
```

Comment: Are you loading the media from the same domain as the page?